# How I can forward the initialisation params of a generic struct in a template?

Tags: c++

I have the following template for a struct

```
template <typename Element> struct MyFoo
{
  std::vector<Element> elements = {};

  void addElement(const Element &element)
  {
    elements.emplace_back(element);
  }
};
```

And with this code if I want to add an element to the vector through a function has to be like this

```
struct FooParams {
  float x;
};

struct Foo
{
  float a;

  Foo(FooParams params = {.x = 0.0f}) {
    a = params.x * 2.0f;
  }
};

MyFoo<Foo> myFoo;

Foo foo({
  .x = 1.0f,
});

myFoo.addElement(foo);
```

This is okay but it would be nicer if I could forward the constructor params to the addElement so I could do something like this instead

```
myFoo.addElement({
  .x = 1.0f,
});
```

The error that the compiler gives with this is

```
error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const Foo&'
   35 | myFoo.addElement({
      | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
   36 |   .x = 1.0f,
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~     
   37 | });
      | ~~               
note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void MyFoo<Element>::addElement(const Element&) [with Element = Foo]'
    9 |   void addElement(const Element &element)
```

Could be possible to do this with a c++ template?

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I updated the question to make it as minimal as possible

Comment: `myFoo.addElement(1.0f);` is ok. You want to keep the designated initializer? I already get a compiler error for your "ok" code: https://godbolt.org/z/91d7xGfeW

Comment: if i am not mistaken, `Foo` is not an aggreate, because it has a user declared constructor, hence `Foo foo({ .a = 1.0f,});` is not allowed. You could remove the user defined constructor

Comment: with your latest edit, the "not ok" code *is* ok: https://godbolt.org/z/dvEr6Y3Gc

Comment: please post a [mcve] together with the compiler error message

Comment: I think you're looking for `reflection` which isn't part of `c++` yet.

Comment: I updated the example, I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I saw you change the example code, and in the example you provide it would work just fine. Tested on g++ 8.3.0

---

On the older code you had posted, the Quad2 class had a constructor which required an object, not a list of floats as you expected. I'll post similar code here:

```
class Render {
  void foo(const Foo& obj);
}

struct FooParams {
  float x0, y0, x1, y1;
}

struct Foo {
  Foo(FooParams = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f});
}
```

Then you want to do a call like:

```
Render myRender;
myRender.foo( {1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f} );
```

The point here is that only one object is generated from that initialization list while the Foo class needs a FooParams object to work.

---

The solutions are two:

```
myRender.foo( {{1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f}} );
```

Notice the double brackets: first the compiler creates a FooParams object (first set of brackets) then it passes it to the constructor of the Foo struct (second brackets).

---

The second solution is adding a constructor of Foo that requires only floats:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1);
  Foo(FooParams = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f});
}
```

And then call:

```
myRender.foo( {1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f} );
```

Comment: The solution for `myRender.foo( {{1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f}} );` works

Comment: The problem with the only float constructor is that I can't do {.x0 = 1.0f, .y1 = 2.0f }